# Integrating over data points from an external source (wolfram|alpha and weather)

Tags: numerical-integration, data-acquisition

I moved to another city and the weather sucks.

Sometimes I feel like getting sad and so I go to *wolfram|alpha* and check for example

${}$

[image]

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=weather+in+Rome+vs.+London

${}$

Today I feel like getting depressed.

Consequently I wonder if there is a way to import all the data into *Mathematica* and write a function

```
TemperatureComparison[{city1,city2},{date1,date2}]
```

which should evaluate to

$$
\frac{
\int_{\text{date 1}}^{\text{date 2}} 
\left(T_{\text{city 2}}(t)-T_{\text{city 1}}(t)\right) 
\text dt
}
{
t_{\text{date 2}}-t_{\text{date 1}}
},$$

$T_{\text{city X}}(t)$ being the temperature in $\text{city X}$ at time $t$.

Comment: You've seen `WeatherData[]`?

Comment: You can get the data out of Wolfram|Alpha pretty easily. Take a look at this article for an example:
http://support.wolfram.com/kb/7357
The data here is financial, but the process is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by @J.M. you don't need WolframAlpha. One way is to define :

```
temperatureComparison[{city1_, city2_}, {date1_, date2_}] := 
 Module[{data1, data2, int1, int2},
  data1 = {AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@  WeatherData[city1, "MeanTemperature", {date1, date2, "Day"}] ;
  data2 = {AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@ WeatherData[city2, "MeanTemperature", {date1, date2, "Day"}] ;
  int1 = Interpolation[data1];
  int2 = Interpolation[data2];
  {#, NIntegrate[
   int1[t] - int2[t], {t, AbsoluteTime[date1], 
    AbsoluteTime[#]}]/(AbsoluteTime[#] - AbsoluteTime[date1])} & /@    
     NestList[DatePlus[#, 1] &, DatePlus[date1, 1], Round@DateDifference[date1, date2] - 1]
```

]

which you can use as :

```
output = temperatureComparison[{"Rome", {"London", "GreaterLondon",  
     "UnitedKingdom"}}, {{2012, 1, 1}, Date[]}]

 DateListPlot[output]
```

[image]